# As3 preload/render a single movieclip before addChild to stage

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, preload, addchild

I have some problems. I want to preload a single movieclip instead of preloading the whole project. Is there a way to that.

Concept Game.
Intro Displayed - Intro removed - Title Dislplayed - Title removed "after pressing on screen"
[[[[[[[PRELOAD CUT SCENE]]]]]]] if completed display CUT SCENE.

Thats the plan, but i do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do that. But you need several SWFs for that, each containing a single movie clip that you want to be separately preloaded. You make a Loader object for each one, you have an URL for each one, then you call `Loader.load()` at appropriate time (say, after successfully preloading previous one) and assign a Event.COMPLETE listener that would fire once the movieclip is loaded. Don't forget to assign an error event loader as well, otherwise your game would stuck should it fail to preload a cut scene. More [in the documentation for Loader class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html).

Comment: Hello there thank you for the answer. Does this method also work for air application?

Comment: Should do, if that AIR application is loaded from elsewhere but local storage. Otherwise you don't even need this.